# Travis doesn't add my Repository

Tags: php, git, github, travis-ci

I signed up for Travis Ci, and **flicked the switch / enabled ** my repo.

I have a .travis.yml file that has been linted and is correct.

When I do a git push, it doesn't do anything and it doesn't show up on my repos in the sidebar. It does not add my repo to travis, and if I refresh the page. It asks me to login to github again.

And then, I see that the **switch has been flicked off**.

Any idea how to get Travis working?

Comment: What happens when you switch it on back again?